# How exactly do I set up Entity Framework to work with DB2

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, db2, entity-framework-5

We are running on DB2 9.7.  I wrote a WPF app that uses EF 5 to connect to my MSSQL dev server.  I now need to switch that to use the DB2 server.

I have a new connection string, but the provider name is giving me trouble.  I keep getting exceptions that when trying to execute queries that the provier is not registered or not installed.

My connection string is located in the app.config file as such:

```
<add name="TIMSContext" connectionString="Database=DB2C;UID=myUser;PWD=myPWD;Server=MVSDEVL:446;" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2" />
```

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546120/is-it-possible-to-use-entity-framework-with-a-db2-iseries-as-400
and this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376433/entity-framework-for-db2

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change my app to compile as x86 to get the right drivers...