# Entity framework provider error with IBM DB2 I Series database

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, db2-400

Ok here's my problem I want to use entity framework with a DB2 for I series database, in a database first way, but it has been really complicated to get a successful connection.

First I was trying to create an Entity Data model using the "IBM DB2 and IDS Servers" Data source but although I created a successful connection to a LUW DB2 I haven't been able to do it with the DB2 for I series, I have tried ports 446 it said there was a licence problem, 9471 generated a connection error, 8471 kept waiting and 50000 with no success, I even tried using no port, but it didn't work.

[image: Data source selection]

[image: Connection properties]

So I choosed to use the IBM DB2 for i data source, this option allows me to connect but when I try to use Entity Framework 6.1.3 I get an error telling me that EF 6.x is not compatible with this version.

[image: Data source for i series]

[image]

So, I downgraded EF to version 5.0 to try to create the Entity Model any way and then upgrade the EF version, but, when I click on next after selecting EF 5.0 the Entity Data Model Wizard disappears before showing the database objects and settings and the model doesn't get created.

Then I decided I didn't need an edmx file I could do the mapping manually now that the connection is working so I started creating the classes to do the mapping:

AppContext:

```
public class AppContext: DbContext
{
    public AppContext() : base( "connectionString" )
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Data> Datas { get; set; }
}
```

Data:
    [Table("data")]
    public class Data
    {
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

```
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the test:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var ctx = new AppContext())
        {
            Data data = new Data() { Id = 1, Name = "A Name" };

            ctx.Datas.Add(data);
            ctx.SaveChanges();                
        }
    }
}
```

I installed the EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 nuget version 6.0.7 and changed my Web.config to add the connection string, I found there a new provider named "IBM.Data.DB2" and tested the connection but I began having the same problems I had with the first connection, with the different ports.

So I thought that this provider must be the one for the first connection and I needed the one for I series son I changed provider to "IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" and tried again changing some parameters in the connection string but now I'm getting this error:

> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Here are my connection strings and providers from my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB2Connection" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2" connectionString="DataSource=192.168.1.54;UserID=XXXX;DefaultCollection=XXXX;Database=DB10000010; Password=XXXXXX;" />
    <add name="connectionString" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" connectionString="Server=192.168.1.54;UserID=XXXXX;Database=DB100000010; Password=XXXXX;" />
</connectionStrings>

<providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="IBM.Data.DB2" type="IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework.DB2ProviderServices, IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework, Version=10.5.5.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208" />
    <provider invariantName="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" type="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26" />
</providers>
```

I also found a new IBM I Access that is supposed to replace the old IBM DB2 i series for windows provider, but couldn't find a data source that works with it

[image: IBM I Access app]

Ok so I'm running out of ideas, Can anyone help me to use entity framework with IBM DB2 for i series?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it's telling you that you can't use the provider with EF6... so don't use EF6. Use EF5, which, as far as I know, is still running in a lot of places.

Comment: I downgraded EF to version 5.0 but I'm still getting an error, this is the new error: A null was returned after calling the 'GetService' method on a store provider instance of type 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.DB2Factory'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.

Comment: I have no idea; I just saw that you kept trying to get it to work with EF6 and that just ain't gonna work if the provider doesn't support it. You may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20376433/215552); it's a bit old, but my get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: When you downloaded the new ACS, did you also download "Windows Application package"?  That's where the ODBC, .NET, & OLEDB drivers are.  Note that the windows application package must be downloaded from  the Entitled System Support (ESS) website: https://www-304.ibm.com/servers/eserver/ess/index.wss

Comment: EF 6.1.3 is fully supported with the IBM i DB2 database. You need to use IBM's DB2 Connect product and the 6.0.7 Nuget package you are referencing. The issue is though, they do not provide the IBM.Data.DB2 via a nuget package. You have to add it manually by going here: C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40 for the 64bit version. You must then change your build profile to be 64bit only.

Comment: Also, IBM DB2 and IDS Servers is the correct option to choose, the iSeries one is only for ADO.NET

Comment: would it work setting a connection with no port?

Comment: I added the reference to the IBM.Data.DB2.dll to the project and tested the connection again but I'm still getting "A comunication error has been detected" when using the "IBM DB2 and IDS Servers" Data source.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am getting the same error trying to connect to an ISeries using the same process as above.

Comment: No luck sorry :(

Comment: You need to buy the DB2 connect

Answer (score 0):

To connect with DB2 iSeries you must connect using port 446.
There is a licesing issue.
You must contact IBM to obtain your license:

ADM12008C  The product "IBM Data Server Driver Package" does not have 
          a valid license key installed and the evaluation period has expired. 
          Functions specific to this product are not enabled. If you have 
          licensed this product, ensure the license key is properly installed. 
          You can install the license using the db2licm command. The license 
          file can be obtained from your licensed product CD.

Follow this link for more information:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9a107d00-d814-440c-b438-faa4d020ae1a&ps=100