# Getting started using Entity Framework with DB2

Tags: entity-framework, db2

This is my first time building a .NET application that connects to a DB2 database, and I really have no idea where to begin as I've never worked with DB2 before.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework
2. Installed IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries
3. Installed Entity Framework 6

Now when I try to create a code first model, I don't see DB2 in the list of available data sources, so I'm guessing I need to figure that out first.

[image: Choose Data Source window]

**What do I need to do to get DB2 added as a data source?** I know it's possible because I can see it in the first screenshot in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727930/entity-framework-provider-error-with-ibm-db2-i-series-database) previously answered question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install IBM Data Server Client Packages and IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio